# Are multiple operations for string formatting allowed in Python?

Tags: python, string-formatting, pep8

Could be a basic one:

I am just trying to do **multiple operations on one of the key in a dictionary** with encoding the first element of the key, splitting it further based on a character and also joining with another string as below:

```
images_list["RepoTag"] = image["RepoDigests"][0].encode("utf-8").split("@")[0] + ":none"
```

Code snippet in which I am doing the above formatting:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
import requests

@require_http_methods(["GET"])
def images_info(request):
    response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:6000/images/json")
    table = []
    images_list = {}
    for image in response.json():
        try:
            images_list["RepoTag"] = image["RepoTags"][0].encode("utf-8")
        except TypeError:
            images_list["RepoTag"] = image["RepoDigests"][0].encode("utf-8").split("@")[0] + ":none"
        images_list["Id"] = image["Id"].encode("utf-8")[7:19]
        table.append(images_list)
        images_list = {}

    return JsonResponse(table,safe=False)
```

Can someone tell me whether is it the right way to do these many operations in a single line? or in another way **Does it follows the python standards ?**

If not does **python standards suggest any limited operations in a single line or so**?

Reason for asking this is that the number of characters should not exceed 79 characters as per [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).

Comment: Are you sure you mean "operations on one of the **key** in a dictionary"?

Comment: If it ain't broken, don't fix it.

Comment: @Shiva [The Cub Scout Rule](http://pragmaticcraftsman.com/2011/03/the-boy-scout-rule/): Leave the campsite cleaner than you found it.

Comment: Perhaps you need to create more local variables with friendly names to make the code as readable as possible. But the final decision is yours. It is also worth following the recommendations of PEP8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with chaining a few string operations together. If you want to keep it within the 80-character line, just add some parentheses:

```
images_list["RepoTag"] = (
    image["RepoDigests"][0].encode("utf-8").split("@")[0] + 
    ":none")
```

or use `str.format()` to provide those same parentheses:

```
images_list["RepoTag"] = '{}:none'.format(
    image["RepoDigests"][0].encode("utf-8").split("@")[0])
```

You could, otherwise, trivially use a local variable:

```
first_digest = image["RepoDigests"][0].encode("utf-8")
images_list["RepoTag"] = '{}:none'.format(first_digest.split("@")[0])
```

Comment: thanks.. I liked the str.format() and looks to be clean

Answer (score -1):

It is asked not to exceed 79 characters, but we can do it.

```
    images_list["RepoTag"] = image["RepoDigests"][0].encode("utf-8").split("@")[0] + \
    ":none"
```

OR

```
images_list["RepoTag"] = \
    image["RepoDigests"][0].encode("utf-8").split("@")[0] + ":none"
```

Comment: It's more recommended to use parentheses and not slashes.